# DevExpress Combobox in treelist is disabled

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I try to show a combobox in my TreeList usiong this code:

```
RepositoryItemLookUpEdit rep = new RepositoryItemLookUpEdit();
rep.TextEditStyle = TextEditStyles.DisableTextEditor;

//rep = new RepositoryItemComboBox();
//rep.Items.AddRange(new SecuredObject<QuestionnaireCategory>().PermissionType);
//rep.Items.AddRange(new object[] { "A", "B", "C" });


treeList1.RepositoryItems.Add(rep);

TreeListColumn disciplineColumn = treeList1.Columns.Add();
disciplineColumn.Caption = "Discipline";
disciplineColumn.Visible = true;
disciplineColumn.FieldName = "Entity.Description";
disciplineColumn.OptionsColumn.AllowEdit = false;

TreeListColumn permissionColumn = treeList1.Columns.Add();
permissionColumn.Caption = "Permissie";
permissionColumn.Visible = true;
permissionColumn.Name = "Permission";
//permissionColumn.FieldName = "PermissionType";
permissionColumn.UnboundType = UnboundColumnType.Object;
permissionColumn.ColumnEdit = rep;
//permissionColumn.OptionsColumn.ReadOnly = false;
//permissionColumn.OptionsColumn.AllowEdit = true;

rep.DataSource = permissions;
rep.DisplayMember = "Description";
rep.ValueMember = "Id";
rep.Name = "ola";
rep.ThrowExceptionOnInvalidLookUpEditValueType = true;
```

However, the combo remains empty, it displays '[no data]'. When I set a breakpoint at my datasource, I see that the datasource is filled.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what kind of data source is it? Are you sure you don't need to also set DataMember (e.g. is that a Dataset)?

Comment: I am using a list with custom objects

Comment: What is the datasource (if any) of the treelist? Does the lookupedit/combox appear when you click on the column to edit it.

Comment: The datasource of the treelist is a List of custom types. The custom type is a generic type. All this values are displayed in the treelist. The combo-column only shows a disabled dropdown. I can see that a combo is drawn, but I can not select anything and the combo displays '[no data]'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of your code looks ok, so I suspect it maybe either the missing fieldname or some problem with the datasource.

The following is a tiny sample, most of which is a straight copy of your code (slightly indented) , but I am creating the treelist at runtime and have created a sample generic list to use as a datasource to test it.

At the end of the constructor, for unbound mode , I add a few nodes to the tree otherwise I bind to the datasource and set the fieldname on permissionColumn.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository;
using DevExpress.XtraTreeList.Columns;
using DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls;
using DevExpress.XtraTreeList.Data;

public class Form1 : Form
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }

     public Form1()
    {
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(700, 500);
        DevExpress.XtraTreeList.TreeList treeList1 = new DevExpress.XtraTreeList.TreeList();
        this.Controls.Add(treeList1);
        treeList1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        var permissions = new System.Collections.Generic.List<TestClass>();
        permissions.Add(new TestClass() { Id = 1 , Description = "Permission 1" });
        permissions.Add(new TestClass() { Id = 99, Description = "Permission 99" });

        var list = new System.Collections.Generic.List<TestClass2>();
        list.Add(new TestClass2() { Id = 1 , PermissionId = 1 , Description2 = "List Desc 1" });
        list.Add(new TestClass2() { Id = 2 , PermissionId = 99, Description2 = "List Desc 2" });



                // Your code

                RepositoryItemLookUpEdit rep = new RepositoryItemLookUpEdit();
                rep.TextEditStyle = TextEditStyles.DisableTextEditor;

                //rep = new RepositoryItemComboBox();
                //rep.Items.AddRange(new SecuredObject<QuestionnaireCategory>().PermissionType);
                //rep.Items.AddRange(new object[] { "A", "B", "C" });


                treeList1.RepositoryItems.Add(rep);

                TreeListColumn disciplineColumn = treeList1.Columns.Add();
                disciplineColumn.Caption = "Discipline";
                disciplineColumn.Visible = true;
                disciplineColumn.FieldName = "Entity.Description";
                disciplineColumn.OptionsColumn.AllowEdit = false;

                TreeListColumn permissionColumn = treeList1.Columns.Add();
                permissionColumn.Caption = "Permissie";
                permissionColumn.Visible = true;
                permissionColumn.Name = "Permission";
                //permissionColumn.FieldName = "PermissionType";
                permissionColumn.UnboundType = UnboundColumnType.Object;
                permissionColumn.ColumnEdit = rep;
                //permissionColumn.OptionsColumn.ReadOnly = false;
                //permissionColumn.OptionsColumn.AllowEdit = true;

                rep.DataSource = permissions;
                rep.DisplayMember = "Description";
                rep.ValueMember = "Id";
                rep.Name = "ola";
                rep.ThrowExceptionOnInvalidLookUpEditValueType = true;

                // End Your code


        disciplineColumn.FieldName = "Description2";
        bool unBoundMode = false;
        if (unBoundMode)
        {
            treeList1.AppendNode(new object[] { "Item1", 1 }, -1);
            treeList1.AppendNode(new object[] { "Item2", 99 }, -1);
        }
        else
        {
            treeList1.DataSource = list;
            permissionColumn.FieldName = "PermissionId";
        }


    }

}

public class TestClass
{
    public int Id             { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}


public class TestClass2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PermissionId { get; set; }
    public string Description2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I've tried your code, but it doesn't act the way I want. You've set the datasource of the treeview to `permissions`. In my case I have 2 datasources: 1 for the treelist and 1 for the dropdown. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: I have updated the code to create a second datasource. Note that I have changed the permissionColumn to be bound to a column PermissionID rather than Id and I have also changed disciplineColumn to be bound to Description2 which makes it easier to see which values and columns are relating to which datasource list.

Comment: The changes you are talking about are not visible in your answer, but I understand what you mean, and it works :)

Answer (score 0):

It's that because your setting the column as Unbound

```
...
permissionColumn.UnboundType = UnboundColumnType.Object;
...
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I've commented this line out, but I still get [No data]

Comment: An unbound column should work fine here -- the lookup editor itself is bound but the column in the grid is not. You'll just need to track the grid's unbound column events just like any other unbound editor.

(You *can* have an unbound lookup editor in the grid as well, there's an event that's called something like `GetNotInListItem` on the editor that lets you populate it manually, if you needed to do that. But that's not what you need here.)

Comment: I don't use any events of the treelist

Answer (score 0):

I just went back and checked out Lookup Editors -- I'm pretty sure you need to create columns manually before any data will appear. The DevExpress LookupEditor isn't a simple drop-down, it's basically an embedded grid control. If there's only one property on your item list to display, it would be something like this:

```
  rep.Columns.Add(new LookupColumnInfo("PropertyName", 0));
```